# Joining elements in Python list

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

Given a string, say `s='135'` and a list, say `A=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']`, how can I separate the values in the list that are also in 's' (a digit of s) from the other elements and concatenate these other elements. The output in this example should be: `A=['1','2','3','4','5','67']`. 
Another example:
`s='25'` `A=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']`
output: `A=['1','2','34','5','67']`

Is there a way of doing this without any import statements (this is so that I can get a better understanding of Python and how things work)?

I am quite new to programming so any help would be appreciated!

(Please note: This is part of a larger problem that I am trying to solve).

Comment: `"This is part of a larger problem that I am trying to solve"` which is what? as of now this is probably an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `s` is an integer, not a string

Comment: Why are `2`, `3` and `4` grouped together in the first example? `2` and  `4` are not in `s`, but `3` is.

Comment: I apologise, the way I worded the question isn't very clear. The aim is the group together all the elements that are not in s (not a digit of s that is) and keep the elements that also appear in s separate.

Comment: Okay @bgmn, so is `234` in your first example a mistake?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is. I will change that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with a key that tests for membership in your number (converted to a string). This will group the elements based on whether they are in `s`. The list comprehension will then join the groups as a string.

```
from itertools import groupby

A=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
s=25
# make it a string so it's easier to test for membership
s = str(s)

["".join(v) for k,v in groupby(A, key=lambda c: c in s)]
# ['1', '2', '34', '5', '67']
```

**Edit: the hard way**

You can loop over the list and keep track of the last value seen. This will let you test if you need to append a new string to the list, or append the character to the last string. (Still itertools is much cleaner):

```
A=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
s=25
# make it a string
s = str(s)

output = []
last = None

for c in A:
    if last is None:
        output.append(c)
    elif (last in s) == (c in s):
        output[-1] = output[-1] + c
    else:
        output.append(c)
    last = c

output # ['1', '2', '34', '5', '67']
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, but is there a way of going about this without importing anything?

Comment: Isn't there going to be an input which would provide a funny output since `groupby` requires the input array to be sorted on the same key?

Comment: @bgmn probably, but itertools is in the standard library and it is probably what you should be using for something like this. There's no shame in importing things from the standard library, they are a part of Python.

Comment: But this proves his first one as wrong. The output would be if s=135 ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '67']

[Program finished]

Comment: Right, @High-Octane — that's what the OP has said in the comments. That output matches the edited question.

Comment: @DeepSpace not sure I follow. Can you give an example?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I think he meant index and not the value. I posted an answer.. You seem to be a man who knows his code Mark.. What do you think?

Comment: @bgmn - see edit for a harder method. It's much easier to make mistakes here.

Comment: @ MarkMeyer Thank you so much! The code works for most inputs, but when s=45 the output is ['123', '45', '67'] instead of ['123', '4','5', '67']. Any suggestions?

Comment: @bgmn, if `s=45` why aren't 4 and 5 together since both are in `s`? If you only want to group those `not in s`, you can tweak the logic with `elif (c not in s) and (last not in s):`

Comment: @MarkMeyer I am trying to use the values in s as 'pivot points' so ideally, I would like all the values in s separate from ALL values (including other digits in s). I do apologise for my lack of clarification.

Comment: @bgmn -- I empathize, it's a hard thing to describe. See above comment, if I understand correctly, you can just change the `elif` condition.

Answer (score 0):

A little twist to @Mark's answer?

I think this yields the result.

```
from itertools import groupby

A=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
s=25
# make it a string so it's easier to test for membership
s = str(s)

print(["".join(v) for k,v in groupby(A, key=lambda c: c in s) if str(k) not in s ])
# ['1', '2', '34', '5', '67']
```

Comment: `str(k)` here is just the strings `True` and `False`. Why are you testing if those are in `s`?

Comment: Ohh.. I thought they were index's and since the result was Matching, I thought it was right.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Mark, Are you sure? Then how am I getting the answer for this..

Comment: You are getting that answer because `True` and `False` are never in `s`. Your `if` is always true, making your code identical to mine.

Comment: @MarkMeyer ohh makes sense now, thanks Mark. I'll take this answer down.