# Creating lists within a list Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Given a list of integers `A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]` and a list `p=[4,5,9]` , how can I separate the values in A so that if they do not appear in p, they will be separated into a sub-list dictated by the position of the element of p in A. For example, in this case the output should be `A=[[1, 2, 3], 4, 5, [6, 7, 8], 9].`

```
s=25
# make it a string
s = str(s)

output = []
last = None

for c in A:
    if last is None:
        output.append(c)
    elif (last in s) == (c in s):
        output[-1] = output[-1] + c
    else:
        output.append(c)
    last = c

output # ['1', '2', '34', '5', '67']
```

This is a similar version of the problem that involves a list of strings.

Reference :
[Joining elements in Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813650/joining-elements-in-python-list)

Comment: Hey there, have you written any code to attempt this, that we can look at?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I saw a similar question on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813650/joining-elements-in-python-list and was interested in playing around with this idea

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could show what you have coded so far. Edit your question to include it before this is getting closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by keeping track of all the elements found so far, and resetting the temporary list when you find an element in `p`:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]
p=[4,5,9]

def join_elements(A, p):
    curr = []
    for i in A: # Loop over possible values
        if i in p:
            if curr: # yield and reset current list
                yield curr 
                curr = []
            yield i # yield value from p 
        else: # Add to current list
            curr.append(i)
    if curr: # if we ended with an element that was not in p
        yield curr

print(list(join_elements(A, p)))

# [[1, 2, 3], 4, 5, [6, 7], 9]
```

Comment: @Newbie123 Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you could find a general solution:

```
sub_list = [4, 5, 9]

temp = []
result = []
for i in range(1, 10):

    if i not in sub_list:
        temp.append(i)
        if temp not in result:
            result.append(temp)

    else:
        if len(temp) != 0:
            temp = []
        result.append(i)

print(result)



Output: [[1, 2, 3], 4, 5, [6, 7, 8], 9]
```

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for i in A`? (`A` is not guaranteed to be `range(10)`). Also, this fails if `A` ends with an element not in `p`.

Comment: Thanks @rassar - I have made some corrections and I believe it would work for all types of list. Please correct me if still there is any scope of improvement.